# gitlab CI fails with cloudformation deploy parameter-overrides

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, gitlab, aws-cloudformation

Im trying to automate a cloudformation deploy with gitlab CI, but it is failing with some strange string, this doesnt ocurr locally when i run it

This is the cli call

```
aws --region us-east-1 cloudformation deploy --parameter-overrides file://aws/templates/STAG/us-east-1/us-east-1-1.json --template-file aws/templates/tenable_template.yaml --stack-name STAG-us-east-1-1
```

the  `us-east-1-1.json` parameters file used is as follows

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "TenableName": "STAG-USE1-vpc-066511axxxxd4",
    "VpcId": "vpc-066511axxxxd4",
    "ELBSubnets": "subnet-054adxxxxx9c7,subnet-0f47axxxxac52cd",
    "Location": "USE1",
    "EnvironmentType": "staging"
  }
}
```

and the error code im getting is
 `[u'{'] value passed to --parameter-overrides must be of format Key=Value`

with this `[u'{']` which i dont know or understand what it is

This only happens within the gitlab CI runner, i can run this same code in my machine and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using AWS CLI version 1 if you get the `[u'{']` error.

[AWS CLI version 1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html) does not support `--parameter-overrides` with JSON input.
Try `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest` image in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` which comes with [AWS CLI version 2](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html) preinstalled that supports JSON input.

If you prefer using your own image, here is a [Dockerfile](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/-/blob/master/aws/base/Dockerfile) example:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

ARG DOCKER_VERSION

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bc curl groff jq less unzip zip

# Install docker client
RUN curl "https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz" -o "/tmp/docker.tar.gz" && \
    tar -xzf /tmp/docker.tar.gz -C /tmp/ && \
    cp /tmp/docker/docker* /usr/bin && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/docker* && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*

# Download and unzip aws CLI
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip

# Run AWS install
RUN ./aws/install
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, i used the image you suggested and it worked!

Comment: You are most welcomed